# Make DAO layer independent of the service layer

Tags: java, database, oop, design-patterns, dao

how can I make DAO layer independent of Service layer so that when Db schema has changed i can handle it at DAO layer.

**Edited:** I'm using *Struts 2* JVM framework.
I've developed the UI side and then after i realize something missing in Db. so i have to add some field in Db table. and do some normalization task. it affect the service layer because my modal classes are change due to the Db schema are changed. so, is there any best practice or any design pattern so that i can manage my DAO layer and service layer independently.

Comment: There are many possible answers to this, with frameworks w/o framework etc please share what you have tried so far in order to give an answer appropriate to your case.
A method from your Service and DAO to add an entity to db will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

```
class PersonService
{
   PersonDao  personDao = new PersonDaoOracleImpl();
   public void addPerson(Person person)
   {
     personDao.add(person);
   }
}

class PersonDaoOracleImpl implemets PersonDao{
    public void add(Person)
    {
       //db dependent code here 
    }
}

class Person{
   private String name;
   private String age;
   //getters and setters
}

interface PersonDao{
public void add(Person person);
}
```

Say you moved from Oracle to mysql create a `PersonDaoMysqlImpl` and I prefer this to be autowired (using DependencyInjection) to service class so u need not touch the java class. Other wise you will have to change

```
 PersonDao  personDao = new PersonDaoOracleImpl();
```

line in Service class to

```
 PersonDao  personDao = new PersonDaoMysqlImpl();
```

Comment: good ans. but what when I remove the field age from the database table and add some other fields like gender,address..etc

Comment: then just update the Person Domain class no need to touch any other class except your controller or main class where you populate person object and pass to service methods.